# jQuery autocomplete minLength and maxResults not working

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using jQuery autocomplete in my project and I can't seem to get the `minLength` working.  It will trigger on 1 keypress and I'd like to only show resuults after 4.  My json file has over 300 values that can be returned so I also wanted to use `maxResults` which also doesn't seem to be working for me.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hs9n71jo/)**

JSON

```
{
"projectList": [{
        "label": "Some project",
        "id": "BP003",
        "desc": "Description 1"
    },
    {
        "label": "Some other project",
        "id": "BP065",
        "desc": "Description 2"
    },
    {
        "label": "Complementary ICR",
        "id": "BP122",
        "desc": "Description 3"
    },
    {
        "label": "Project 1",
        "id": "BP129",
        "desc": "Description 4"
    },
    {
        "label": "Another one",
        "id": "BP132",
        "desc": "Description 5"
    }
]
```

}

```js
$("#project").autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
        var regex = new RegExp(request.term, 'i');
        $.ajax({
          url: "projects.json",
          dataType: "json",
          minLength: 4,
          maxResults: 10,
          success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data.projectList, function (item) {
              if (regex.test(item.id)) {
                return {
                  label: item.label,
                  id: item.id
                };
              }
              if (regex.test(item.label)) {
                return {
                  label: item.label,
                  id: item.id
                };
              }
            }));
            
          }
        });
        
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control full-width" id="project" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**minLength** and  **`maxResults`**  is a property of autocomplete  not ajax.

```
$("#project").autocomplete({
      minLength: 4,
      source: function (request, response) {
        var regex = new RegExp(request.term, 'i');
        $.ajax({
          url: testURL,
          dataType: "json",

          maxResults: 10,
          success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data.projectList, function (item) {
              if (regex.test(item.id)) {
                return {
                  label: item.label,
                  id: item.id
                };
              }
              if (regex.test(item.label)) {
                return {
                  label: item.label,
                  id: item.id
                };
              }
            }));

          }
        });

      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check file

assets/js/custom.js for wordpress

and search n modify minLengh or ad maxResults

soroczynski

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).